# Kernel driver receives the struct, but it's still null

Tags: c, kernel, driver

I have a kernel driver for which I'm trying to get ReadFile working. This is my driver dispatch function:

```
NTSTATUS DriverDispatch(PDEVICE_OBJECT DriverObject, PIRP irp)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
PIO_STACK_LOCATION io;
PGAME_INFO info;
NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

io = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(irp);
irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;

if (io->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_WRITE)
{
    io = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(irp);

    CHAR buffer[14] = "Got request\r\n";
    ULONG cb = 14;

    ZwWriteFile(handle, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ioStatusBlock, buffer, cb, NULL, NULL);

    if (io)
    {
        info = (PGAME_INFO)irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
        if (info)
        {
            HANDLE Pid = info->pid;
            cb = 20;

            ZwWriteFile(handle, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ioStatusBlock, Pid, cb, NULL, NULL);

            status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
        else
        {
            CHAR buffer2[20] = "Struct was null\r\n";
            cb = 20;

            ZwWriteFile(handle, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ioStatusBlock, buffer2, cb, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CHAR buffer3[31] = "PIO_STACK_LOCATION is null\r\n";
        cb = 31;

        ZwWriteFile(handle, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ioStatusBlock, buffer3, cb, NULL, NULL);
    }

    irp->IoStatus.Information = sizeof(GAME_INFO);
}
else 
{
    status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

irp->IoStatus.Status = status;

IoCompleteRequest(irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
return status;
}
```

This is the struct I'm using:

```
typedef struct _GAME_INFO {
HANDLE pid;
}GAME_INFO, *PGAME_INFO;
```

And my user mode app:

```
int main()
{
GAME_INFO GameInfo;

HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile("\\\\.\\Driver", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("\nError: Unable to connect to the driver (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    getchar();
    return -1;
}

getchar();

GameInfo.pid = (HANDLE)1234;
DWORD written;

if (!WriteFile(hDevice, &GameInfo, sizeof(GAME_INFO), &written, NULL))
{
    printf("\nError: Unable to write data to the driver (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    CloseHandle(hDevice);
    getchar();
    return -1;
}
else 
{
    printf("%lu", written);
    getchar();
}

CloseHandle(hDevice);
return 0;
}
```

The driver is receiving the request, but the struct is null for some reason. I'm new to kernel drivers and C in general, so feel free to correct me on anything

Comment: When you print out `written`, what does it print?

Comment: It was just something for testing, It printed out the size of the buffer that was written via WriteFile.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure it was printing out what you expected.  I'll assume from your response that it did.  Next question: Are you using direct or buffered IO in the driver?

Comment: As an aside, your "Got request" string handling is error-prone with the magic numbers. Get in the habit of doing things more like `CHAR buffer[] = "Got request\r\n"; ULONG cb = sizeof(buffer);` so you or anyone else can simply change the string and have the rest be automatic.

Comment: I'm using direct, as buffered was BSODing my pc with the error KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

Comment: That's the problem, then.  According to the documentation, SystemBuffer is expected to be NULL in that case.  You probably missed out something you need to do differently for direct IO.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550694(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I've just looked at your other questions.  Are you writing malware to obtain login credentials?

Comment: lol, I'm not writing any malware. If you really wanna know it's for game hacking.

Comment: How is that not malware?  :P

Comment: I'm not stealing users credentials, I'm just reading games memory. This is mostly for educational purposes anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a bit of back-and-forth, this seems to be because the driver IO is set to direct rather than buffered.  There is no system buffer with direct, since it's literally not buffered, so that field is expected to be NULL.

The receiving code needs to work through an MDL instead.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-mdls for a jumping-off point.

Comment: I tried using MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Smurfy - really your device not used direct io too. neither `DO_BUFFERED_IO` nor `DO_DIRECT_IO` are set. so you need use `Irp->UserBuffer` for access user buffer. also because look like you always handle request synchronous - much better use fast io handlers. for use `FastIoRead` or `FastIoWrite` you need also set `PrivateCacheMap` on file object to any not 0 value. if use `FastIoDeviceControl` you not need trick with `PrivateCacheMap`